# Squid limit all user to 128kbit/s

Tags: debian, proxy, squid, debian-squeeze

I have a very odd behaviour with my squid server. It limits every client to a bitrate of exactly 3,2 Mbit/s...

To troubleshoot it, I've tried to set the bitrate limit to unlimited and to 128kbit/s but nothing changed.

The config I used was : (for 128k)

```
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 3
delay_access 1 allow all
delay_parameters 1 64000/64000 -1/-1 16000/64000
```

It's running on a Debian Squeeze with a 3.2-amd64 kernel. Squid version is 2.7.STABLE9.

I use a very same config on another server and the bitrate is unlimited...

Do anyone have a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: The squid versions are the same? They have the same build options?

Comment: Yes, they're from the same debian package, and I've just double checked.